# Super newbie with simple problem with file_exists

Tags: php

I have a PHP form that I am trying to do some troubleshooting but things are not working as expected. When the form loads, I want to see if a file exists in the same directory as the PHP file. I have a log entry routine that works. I have the following code:

```php
$ScriptName= is_file("GetLocalWeather.sh");

logEntry("GetLocalWeather.sh exists? ".$ScriptName);
```

In the log it show the text but it doesn't show the value of `$ScriptName`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Appending boolean values like that doesn't work. You'd need to do something like this:

```php
$scriptName = is_file('GetLocalWeather.sh') ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: $scriptName = is_file('GetLocalWeather.sh') ? 'Yes' : 'No'; maybe yes or no is better than true or false haha

Comment: Both methods came up with a result, but not what I anticipated, the results came back as False/No but the file was actually there?